# Launching felix shell on glassfish

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, osgi, telnet

I am trying to launch the felix shell that would allow me to interact with OSGI runtime on glassfish and start/stop bundles. From what I read it should be accessible via telnet localhost 6666, but when I try to do so I get Connect failed. I tried following the steps mentioned [here](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/osgi.html) but still no luck.

I can't find any other way to access OSGI runtime via shell, does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer was mostly correct except that it lacked the information for 3.1.1. For 3.1.1, you need to add
org.apache.felix.shell.remote.jar to the autostart bundles list in
osgi/felix/config.properties as described in section #10.4.1 of the [osgi features document](http://glassfish.java.net/public/GF-OSGi-Features.pdf).

Comment: It worked after a couple restarts. Thanks a ton sahoo, spent forever trying to see what the problem was.

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell GlassFish to enable the Felix OSGi shell.  How to do that depends on the GlassFish version.

### GlassFish 3.1.1 and earlier:

Stop the server
Edit domain.xml (in your domain's config directory) and add this string:

**org.apache.felix.shell.remote,**

to the value for

**-Dorg.glassfish.additionalOSGiBundlesToStart**

It should look like this:

**-Dorg.glassfish.additionalOSGiBundlesToStart=org.apache.felix.shell.remote,org.apache.felix.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.command**

### GlassFish 3.1.2 and later

asadmin create-jvm-options -Dglassfish.osgi.start.level.final=3

### All Versions

(Re)start the server.

telnet localhost 6666

Comment: I attempted your fix for 3.1.1 and earlier originally (I have 3.1.1) but still kept getting the could not open connection to the host on port 6666, connection failed error. That's why I'm completely stuck, the go to fix I've seen for it doesn't appear to work. For reference, this is my domain.xml file:

Comment: <jvm-options>-Dorg.glassfish.additionalOSGiBundlesToStart=org.apache.felix.shell,org.apache.fe‌​lix.gogo.runtime,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.command,org.ap‌​ache.felix.shell.remote,org.apache.felix.fileinstall</jvm-options>

Answer (score 4):

use GlassFish 3.1.2 and try

```
$ asadmin create-jvm-options -Dglassfish.osgi.start.level.final=3
```

and restart the server. It works.

Answer (score 1):

For Glassfish 4, see Sahoo's document & section; OSGi access no longer uses telnet, but subcommands under asadmin.